# Chaining methods using generics and compositon

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to model series of "phases" C#, where each phase has an input and output, and where they can be chained together, with the output of phase 1 becoming the input of phase 2.  I thought it might look something like this, but I didn't know what to use in place of the ???.

```
public class Phase<TInput, TOutput>
{
  private Phase<???, TInput> prerequisite;

  public Phase(Phase<???, TInput> prereq, Func<TInput, TOutput> work)
  {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

What I'm ultimately trying to do is chain together a series of steps like this (where the "Add" methods are just convenience methods to help me create the phases):

```
var p1 = AddInitialPhase(() => 
  {
    int a = /* some initial result */;
    return a;
  });

var p2 = AddPhase(p1, (result) =>    
  {
    string b = /* do something with result from p1 */
    return b;
  });

var p3 = AddPhase(p2, (result) =>    
  {
    /* etc... */
  });
```

Is there any nice type-safe way to do this with generics?  Or does anyone have design alternatives I should consider?  I can imagine using reflection to do the chaining, or just using objects for the inputs and outputs, but I was hoping there was a better way.

Comment: There's no need for tags in your title, the tag system works. You should give your questions a more describing title so people can see what it's about instead of a very broad description. The use of tags in titles is discussed at http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/147072.

Comment: It sounds like you might be attempting to re-invent monads (or perhaps comonads.) My long series on monads in C# for beginners with no functional programming background might help. http://ericlippert.com/2013/02/21/monads-part-one/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try with two classes:

```
public class OutputOfPhase<TOutput>
{
}

public class Phase<TInput, TOutput> : OutputOfPhase<TOutput>
{
      private OutputOfPhase<TInput> prerequisite;

      public Phase(OutputOfPhase<TInput> prereq, Func<TInput, TOutput> work)
      {
      /* ... */
      }
}
```

and you use it this way:

```
Phase<int, long> p1 = new Phase<int, long>(null, p => p * 1000L);
Phase<long, double> p2 = new Phase<long, double>(p1, p => p / 2.0);
```

A `Phase` class derives from a base class that contains only the output part of the class. You can pass the output of a class to the next class without the next class needing to know the input of the previous object.